# Problema con MongoClient en C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

Tengo las depedencias de Mongo necesarias para el proyecto en VisualStudio 2017 Community pero se genera un error al instanciar la clase MongoClient

Error:

> No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Error de código fuente:

> Línea 25:         var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString);
>
> Línea 27:         var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
>
> Línea 29:         // Use the Mongo URL to avoid hard-coding the database name.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```c#
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using MongoDB.Bson;  
using MongoDB.Driver;  
using System.Configuration;  

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
    protected static IMongoClient _client;  
    protected static IMongoDatabase _database;  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  

        //string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        //MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
        //MongoServerAddress mongoServerAdress = new MongoServerAddress(connectionString);

        // Get your connection string -- use the URL format as in example below:
        // name="MongoConnectionStr" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/bookstore"
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;
        var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString);

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString); //<-- Error aquí

        // Use the Mongo URL to avoid hard-coding the database name.
        var db = new MongoClient(mongoUrl).GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el error de la siguiente manera:
 1. Abrir pestaña `Sitio Web`.
 2. Administrar `Paquetes Nuget`.
 3. Luego pestaña `Examinar` y buscar `InteropServices`.
 4. Seleccioné `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` y `System.Runtime.InteropServices` y escogí la versión que me pedía el error, la 4.0.0 en ambos casos.
 5. Instalé y di sí a todo.

Tambien eliminé el `redirection` del `Web.config` , era una etiqueta debajo de `<assemblyIdentity>` y de está manera dejaron de saltar los errores en la Web.

```
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity 
              name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" 
                publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Marca tu solucion para ayudar a los que tengan este problema.

Comment: Hola, aún no puedo hacerlo, marcaré la solución cuando tenga disponible esta opción.